# How do I figure out what this code is doing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to get my hands dirty by doing some experiments on Data Science using Python and the Pandas library.

Recently I got my hands on a jupyter notebook and stumbled upon a piece of code that I couldn't figure out how it works?

This is the line

```
md['genres'] = md['genres'].fillna('[]').apply(literal_eval).apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [])
```

The dataset comes with a genres column that contains key-value pairs, the code above removes the keys and replaces everything with only the value if more than one value exists a | is inserted as a seperator between the two for instance

Comedy | Action | Drama

I want to know how the code actually works! Why does it need the literal_eval from ast? What is the lambda function doing?! Is there a more concise and clean way to write this?

Comment: With `pandas` it is not that difficult cause methods are chained. So that means you have to follow through what each method is doing, as an example `.fillna()`, `apply(literal_eval)` and so forth to see what changes are happening.

Comment: My recommendation is to split the code up into pieces at each chained function (move each .apply() onto its own line and assign the column anew each time) and check the output after each function is applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time:

```
md['genres'].fillna('[]')
```

This line fills all instances of `NA` or `NaN` in the series with `'[]'`.

```
.apply(literal_eval)
```

This applies [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the `ast` package. We can imply from the fact that `NA` values have been replaced with `'[]'` that the original series contains string representations of lists, so `literal_eval` is used to convert these strings to lists.

```
.apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [])
```

This lambda function applies the following logic: If the value is a list, map to a list containing the `['name']` values for each element within the list, otherwise map to the empty list.

The result of the full function, therefore, is to map each element in the series, which in the original DF is a string representation of a list, to a list of the `['name']` values for each element within that list. If the element is either not a list, or `NA`, then it maps to the empty list.

Answer (score 2):

You can lookup line by line:

```
md['genres'] = md['genres'].fillna('[]')
```

This first line ensures `NaN` cells are replaced with a string representing an empty list. That's because column `genres` are expected to contain lists.

```
                           .apply(literal_eval)
```

The method `ast.literal_eval` is used to actually evaluate dictionaries, and not use them as strings. Thanks to that, you can further access keys and values. See more [here](https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval).

```
                           .apply(
                             lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x]
                                       if isinstance(x, list) 
                                       else []
                             )
```

Now you're just applying some function that will filter your lists. These lists contain dictionaries. The function will return all dictionary values associated with key `name` within your inputs if they're lists. Otherwise, that'll be an empty list.